# Optional binding bug on Swift 2.2?

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors, optional-binding

```
if let mathematicalSymbol = sender.currentTitle {
    brain.performOperation(mathematicalSymbol)
}
```

The code above introduces the error below;

> Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use
>   '!' or '?'?

As can be seen in this screen shot;

[image]

`sender.currentTitle` is an optional.

Here is an excerpt from Apple's "[The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID1)" with its example code just below it;

> If the optional value is `nil`, the conditional is `false` and the code
>   in braces is skipped. Otherwise, **the optional value is *unwrapped*** and
>   assigned to the constant after `let`, which makes the ***unwrapped value***
>   available inside the block of code.

Here is the sample code for that excerpt;

```
var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"
var greeting = "Hello!"
if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

So for these reasons, I'm thinking that either I'm **missing something** or that I'm **hitting a bug**.

I've also tried something similar on a Playground, and didn't get a similar error;

[image]

Here is my Swift version;

```
Apple Swift version 2.2 (swiftlang-703.0.18.8 clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

Comment: Possibly related: [The strange behaviour of Swift's AnyObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388830/the-strange-behaviour-of-swifts-anyobject).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at `currentTitle`, you'll see it is likely inferred to be `String??`. For example, go to `currentTitle` in Xcode and hit the <kbd>esc</kbd> key to see code completion options, and you'll see what type it thinks it is:

[image]

I suspect you have this in a method defining `sender` as `AnyObject`, such as:

```
@IBAction func didTapButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let mathematicalSymbol = sender.currentTitle {
        brain.performOperation(mathematicalSymbol)
    }
}
```

But if you explicitly tell it what type  `sender` is, you can avoid this error, namely either:

```
@IBAction func didTapButton(sender: UIButton) {
    if let mathematicalSymbol = sender.currentTitle {
        brain.performOperation(mathematicalSymbol)
    }
}
```

Or

```
@IBAction func didTapButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let button = sender as? UIButton, let mathematicalSymbol = button.currentTitle {
        brain.performOperation(mathematicalSymbol)
    }
}
```

Comment: `if let mathematicalSymbol = (sender as? UIButton)?.currentTitle {` also works.

Comment: I find it annoying that Xcode defaults to `AnyObject` for the `sender` type.  `AnyObject` is rarely what anyone would want for the sender, so the user should have to choose it if they really want it, IMHO.

Comment: Agreed. When I drag-and-drop my `IBAction` connections, I always pick the specific type in the dropdown, rather than accepting the `AnyObject` default. I disliked this latter behavior in Objective-C, and it's even worse now, being so unswifty.

Comment: @Rob, you're right on point.

This was the exact issue I was experiencing, upon checking the type of my `sender`, I noticed that it was `AnyObject` as you guessed.

I always try to change it but forgot to do so in this occasion, hence this error. When I used `UIButton`, it was resolved. Also, checking the type of `UIButton` shows as `String?` as expected - as opposed to `String??` for `AnyObject`.

Apple really should change the behaviour of defaulting to `AnyObject`. Thanks a lot!