# Swift: NSDate.day returning nil

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to access a NSDate variable stored within coredata as AnyObject and print the day. When I print it, it returns nil. When I print the Date without .day after it it prints the correct value.
Edit: workoutDate is an attribute of the entity 'Workout' and is of type 'Date'

```
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        do {
            let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Workout")
            let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

            if results.count > 0 {
                for item in results as! [Workout]{


                    let time = item.valueForKey("workoutTime")
                    let currentWorkoutDate = item.valueForKey("workoutDate")
                    let workoutDateDay = currentWorkoutDate!
                    print(workoutDateDay)
                    print(workoutDateDay.day!)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSDate` has no `day` property. However, the Key-Value coding method

```
let currentWorkoutDate = item.valueForKey("workoutDate")
```

returns an `AnyObject?` and you can call *any* (existing) Objective-C method on that object
(compare [The strange behaviour of Swift's AnyObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388830/the-strange-behaviour-of-swifts-anyobject)). The compiler does not complain because `day`
is a property of `NSDateComponents`. But at runtime, it is detected that
the object does not respond to this property, and therefore
`workoutDateDay.day` is `nil`.

The solution is to convert the value to an `NSDate` object:

```
if let workoutDate = item.valueForKey("workoutDate") as? NSDate {
    // ...
}
```

or better, create a `NSManagedObject` subclass for the entity
and use the property accessors.

Then use the `NSCalender` methods to get `NSDateComponents` from the
date, for example

```
if let workoutDate = item.valueForKey("workoutDate") as? NSDate {
    let day = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Day, fromDate: workoutDate)
    print(day)
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This clears up the problem!

Comment: Im getting the error 'Type Int has no member Day' when I try to print day

Comment: @RyanHampton: did you copy the code exactly? It works for me. The `component(.Day, fromDate: workoutDate)` method returns the day as an Int, you don't have to access `.day` on the return value. Alternatively, use `components(.Day, fromDate: workoutDate)`

Comment: I get an error of 'use of unresolved identifier workoutDate' on the line let day = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Day, fromDate: workoutDate)

Answer (score 1):

CoreData returns `NSDate` which has no method `day`.
So, your problem is in that method if you have added it.

Comment: If this is the case then why does it pop up as an option when I add a full stop (period) after typing in workoutDate?

Comment: @RyanHampton because it's anytype, but you know it will always be NSDate so just: let currentWorkoutDate = item.valueForKey("workoutDate") as! NSDate

Comment: @RyanHampton If you hold down that ALT key and click on the variable, then Xcode will tell you what type it is. Then you can always find out if the type you expected is being interpreted.

Comment: Ah thats useful. Thank you!